# Spring data, JPA, Hibernate - bidirectional relationship infinite recursion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with StackOverflowError due to infinite recursion.
My configs:

applicatinContext.xml (part)

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true"
    p:persistenceProviderClass="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath:persistence.xml"
    p:persistenceUnitName="hibernate-persistent"
    p:packagesToScan="pl.roszkow.webpage.entities"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="pl.roszkow.webpage.repositories"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="hibernate-persistent" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite::resource:roszkow.db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>

    <!-- SQL -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">pl.roszkow.webpage.utils.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

    <!-- C3P0 -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/securityContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/securityContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And now my entities, User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3170642319755386686L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp birthDate;

    private Boolean enabled = false;

    private String role = "ROLE_USER";

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Article> articles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(this.role));
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }
}
```

and Article.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6523854154438579850L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "{article.title.notBlank}")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @NotBlank(message = "{article.content.notBlank}")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "add_date", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp addDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private User author;

    /*@OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
    private List<Image> images;*/
}
```

repositories, UsersRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

List<User> findAll();

User findOne(Long id);

User findByEmail(String email);

User save(User user);
}
```

ArticlesRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface ArticlesRepository extends CrudRepository<Article, Long> {

@Query("select a from Article a order by a.addDate desc")
List<Article> findAll();

Article findOne(Long id);

Article save(Article article);

void delete(Long id);
}
```

Error occurs when app is trying to load the articles collection in User entity. But with lazy loading the collection shuldn't at all be loaded. When deleting the collection from class everything works fine.

Could anyone say me what is wrong with my app? I suppose that lazy loading isn't working properly.

Earlier I had also problem with LazyInitializationException, but solved it by adding SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter to web.xml.

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.Long.stringSize(Long.java:306)
java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:242)
java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:100)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2945)
java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:740)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.Article.toString(Article.java:30)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.User.toString(User.java:35)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.Article.toString(Article.java:30)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.User.toString(User.java:35)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.Article.toString(Article.java:30)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.User.toString(User.java:35)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.Article.toString(Article.java:30)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.User.toString(User.java:35)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
pl.roszkow.webpage.entities.Article.toString(Article.java:30)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
```

Comment: where is your image class. Can you add its code

Comment: please post your stacktrace of the error ....

Comment: Added stacktrace. @TanviB I commented out the images collection, error persist.

Comment: Is this really your full Entity? To me it would look like you also have a `toString` method which is actually the culprit. Also do you really need a bi-directional relation ship, does the `User` really need the `Articles`? Or could you simply issue an additional query when you need the articles. Is the `User` less a `User` when it doesn't directly know it's articles? Think of it from a functional pov not a relational pov.

Comment: @M.Deinum you got me here, truly there exist toString method, but I didn't suspect that this would be the problem and didn't mention about it for code clarity. This is the right answer - whene deleting `toString` methods evrything works fine.

Comment: Just read the stack trace, that clearly loops in a `toString`. You probably output everything including the `articles`, the article in turn does a `toString` on user again. You can also simply fix the `toString` to not call the `toString` of article (just output a small amount of data) or the `Article` to String only outputs the `username` of the user instead of the full `toString`.

Comment: I modified `toString` method acording to your suggestions. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this: add @JsonBackReference

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
private User author;
```

**edit:**

try it with

```
@JsonManagedReference
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private User author;
```

Comment: Added annotation, but nothing changed, error persist

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6523854154438579850L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
....
```

and

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6523854154438579850L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
....
```